# A cylinder is (possibly) cut by another cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, 3d, cylindrical-coordinates

Consider two cylinders $C_{s}$ (solid) and $C_{h}$ (hollow):

Cylinder $C_{s}$ has a radius $r_{s}$, and has the points $(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2},z_{2})$ as the centers of its bases.

Cylinder $C_{h}$ has a radius $r_{h}$, and has the points $(x_{3},y_{3},z_{3})$ and $(x_{4},y_{4},z_{4})$ as the centers of its bases (no solid bases).

The hollow cylinder, $C_{h}$, acts as a cutter, where it moves a distance $d$ in the direction of the outward-pointing normal at either $(x_{3},y_{3},z_{3})$ or $(x_{4},y_{4},z_{4})$, whichever specified. So the axis is fixed.

---

In some cases, the cutter will never cross the solid cylinder, regardless of $d$.

In some cases, the cutter will cross the solid cylinder, but will not form a complete cut. Say when $d$ is not enough.

In some cases, when $d$ is large enough, and the axes are parallel and the base of $C_{h}$ will entirely cross the base of $C_{s}$. In this case we will have cut piece that is "exactly" cylindrical in shape.

Also there are other cases, say when the axes are perpendicular and $r_{s}>r_{h}$, so we will have a cut that is "not exactly" cylindrical in shape (it has curvy bases).

Furthermore, when the axes are neither parallel nor perpendicular, then the resultant piece may or may not have a part of the base of $C_{s}$ depending upon the direction of the cutter.

Keeping in mind the cases when $r_{s}>r_{h}$ and when $r_{s}<r_{h}$.

And there are many other cases are there!

I wish I can do some illustrations like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377613/cross-section-of-a-sphere-cut-by-cylinder) (NOT EXACTLY SAME). I am having two cylinders.

---

The simplest case when the cylinders do not cross each other, the volume is $0$.

For uncomplete cut, the volume should be considered as $0$.

---

Given $r_{s}, r_{h}, (x_{1},y_{1},z_{1}) ,(x_{2},y_{2},z_{2}) ,(x_{3},y_{3},z_{3}) ,(x_{4},y_{4},z_{4}), d$ and the direction, can we evaluate the volume of the cut piece, if any, without specifying the case?

Is there any explicit formula for this?

Comment: General explicit formula can be written using cases environment, but it will be long.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu What is that, exactly? I really have no idea about "cases environment". Please help. Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: $$V(r_s,r_h,x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2,x_3,y_3,z_3,x_4,y_4,z_4,d)=\begin{cases}
V_1(...),\ {\rm some\ condition\ involving\ input\ variables}\\
V_2(...),\ {\rm some\ condition\ involving\ input\ variables}\\
0,\ {\rm some\ condition\ involving\ input\ variables} \end{cases}$$

Comment: The cases where the two cylinder axes intersect has been worked out by Hubbell in https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/69C/jresv69Cn2p139_A1b.pdf (J. Res. Nat. Bur. Standards 69C (2) (1965)

Comment: @R.J.Mathar That link shows: "Bad Request - Invalid URL"